# Trouble calling pointer to member function

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to call a function pointer that points to a member function and I either get the error

> Error 3   error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0
>   arguments

or

> Error 3   error C2171: '*' : illegal on operands of type 'Foo::func_t

my code looks like

```
class Foo
{
   void stuff();
   void more_stuff();
   void my_func();

   typedef void(Foo::* func_t)(void);
   func_t fptr;
};

void Foo::my_func()
{
   //do some stuff
}

void Foo::stuff()
{
   fptr = &Foo::my_func;
}

void Foo::more_stuff()
{
   if(fptr != 0)
   {
       (*fptr)(); //error C2171: '*' : illegal on operands of type 'Foo::func_t
       (fptr)(); //term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
   }
}
```

Can anyone see the issue here?

Comment: And which object of the class will the function have for `this`? You haven't specified any such object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
(this->*fptr)();
```

This is required since it's a *member* function pointer and you need to explicitly provide an instance to work on when using `fptr`. It might look like the compiler could already use the implicit `*this`, but that is not what the standard says and hence you need to take care of it manually.

Comment: Wow, that's tricky. I thought this was always implicitly called on everything done in a class. But sure enough, that got it to compile.